# Glob-like brace Wildcards in Bash

Tags: bash, list, conditional-statements, glob, rm

Lets say I've a directory `/etc/php5/conf.d/`, with the following hypothetical files in it:

```
mysql.ini
mysqli.ini
20-mysql.ini
20-mysqli.ini
20-pdo_mysql.ini
```

I would like to delete all these files except the last one (`pdo`), this is what I have at the moment:

```
for phpIni in mysql mysqli; do
    if [[ -f /etc/php5/conf.d/$phpIni.ini ]]; then
        rm /etc/php5/conf.d/$phpIni.ini
    if [[ -f /etc/php5/conf.d/20-$phpIni.ini ]]; then
        rm /etc/php5/conf.d/20-$phpIni.ini
    fi
done
```

It works, but I can't help noticing that the above could be simplified with glob patterns, such as:

```
if [[ ! -z /etc/php5/conf.d/{,20-}mysql*ini ]]; then
    rm /etc/php5/conf.d/{,20-}mysql*ini
fi
```

There's a problem though, if the any of the expansions doesn't exists, `rm` will complain about it:

```
$ if [[ ! -z /etc/php5/conf.d/{,20-}mysql*ini ]]; then rm /etc/php5/conf.d/{,20-}mysql*ini; fi
rm: cannot remove `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-mysql*ini': No such file or directory
```

How can I make rm only remove existing files? Or at least prevent it from throwing all these errors?

Comment: That `if` test won't do what you want. `[[ ! -z /etc/php5/conf.d/{,20-}mysql*ini ]]` is always true, whether any files matching the pattern exist or not. I think this is because bash doesn't do pattern matching in this context, but even if it did it still wouldn't work because an unmatched pattern is left unexpanded (unless you do a `shopt -s nullglob` first).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I tested it with an `echo` instead of the `rm` command, and it only seems echo the string when at least one of the files exists. Am I missing something?

Comment: Very strange; it always executes the `echo` for me (although if nullglob is set, the `echo` just prints a blank line). What version of bash are you using? I have 3.2.48(1)-release.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I'm using the 4.2.24(1)-release that comes with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. Is there anyway I can confirm the current status flags of `shopt`?

Comment: `shopt nullglob` will print its current status (and `shopt` alone will print the status of all settable options).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Weird, it returns `nullglob        off`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rm -f`, it will not complain if files don't exist: as seen in the man page,
"ignore nonexistent files, never prompt".

Comment: I did read the man page, but somehow my eyes missed the `f` flag... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a *-f* as an rm parameter will prevent that. On the flipside, though, you need to ensure your glob is solid, lest you delete too much.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and I think it's alright for my needs. Either way, these are only symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `shopt -s nullglob` -- if there are no files matching the pattern, the null string is substituted instead of the pattern string.

To delete all except one, use

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*pdo*).ini
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat trick right there! Unfortunately, it wouldn't work as I also have more `.ini` files that I want to keep. Regarding `shopt` would you mind reading the comment I left to @GordonDavisson?

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. I don't know what your concern is